# GCM sometimes return 401 Unauthorized

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I connected GCM service a few weeks ago and it worked fine till todays launch time. Unfoternately, after launch 7.01 GCM  returned to me 'Client error: `POST https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send` with `401 Unauthorized` response' and nothing helps to solve this issue. All I found, when I remove everything from 'Accept requests from these server IP addresses' in API key credentials, GCM began work, but sometimes it returns 401 status again. What happened? This situation confused me.﻿

Comment: Are you using [HTTP Connection Server](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http)? It's either an invalid API key or the GCM Server rejected the request. I'm leaning to the latter since you're calling `send`. The [response format](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#response) section describes the possible reason from the errors returned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Go to the [project console](https://cloud.google.com/console/project)
2. Click your project
3. Go to APIs & auth in the left panel
4. Select APIs in the sub-menu
5. Search Google Cloud Messaging for Android (or/and Chrome) and turn it on

Comment: Yeah, GCM is already turned on, API key created as "Server", all works fine till 7.01. Now, 10.01, 85% of requests are success, but 15% return 401